# Drawing routes combining a geographic dataset and a dataset containing routes in R

Tags: r, line, sf, route, centroids

I want to draw migration routes on a map in R. The basic idea is that I have a dataset containing 3 municipalities inside Mexico through which an individual has passed. I want to draw a line connecting these 3 municipalities. But then repeat for like 20k individuals!

I have the shapefile for Mexican municipalities from the World Bank. I can easily plot the shapefile to obtain a map of Mexico with these. I also have codes for each municipality-state pair, given by variables CVE_ENT and CVE_MUN. (https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/mexico-municipalities-2012)

Then, for an example, suppose I have a dataframe with one row:

```
route <- as.data.frame(t(c("08", "019", "26", "019", "26", "039")))
colnames(route) <- c("CVE_ENT2", "CVE_MUN2", "CVE_ENT3", "CVE_MUN3","CVE_ENT4", "CVE_MUN4")
```

So, as you can see, this row contains codes for three cities (six variables, three municipality-state pairs). These three cities can be found in the shapefiles. What I want is to create a new sf file that contains a line connecting these three municipalities. Then I can plot both the map of Mexico and the route.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get your route into a row-oriented order with names that match the columns in the municipalities:

```
> route = data.frame(matrix(c("08", "019", "26", "019", "26", "039"),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
> route
  X1  X2
1 08 019
2 26 019
3 26 039
> names(route)=c("CVE_ENT","CVE_MUN")
> route
  CVE_ENT CVE_MUN
1      08     019
2      26     019
3      26     039
```

Then you can merge this with the municipalities to get out the geometry for those route locations. Note you have to convert

```
> muni = st_read("Muni_2012gw.shp")
> routem = st_as_sf(merge(route, muni))

Simple feature collection with 3 features and 6 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -110.5402 ymin: 28.09585 xmax: -105.7028 ymax: 31.33414
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  CVE_ENT CVE_MUN   NOM_MUN OID_1 cov_ cov_id                       geometry
1      08     019 Chihuahua   335  335    336 MULTIPOLYGON (((-106.231 29...
2      26     019   Cananea  1912 1912   1913 MULTIPOLYGON (((-110.2945 3...
3      26     039      Naco  1896 1896   1897 MULTIPOLYGON (((-109.9207 3...
```

Now you can do stuff with that. EG plot the country and then add those three:

```
> plot(muni$geom)
> plot(routem$geom, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

If you want to draw it as a line you need some points to connect up. You could start by trying the centroids.

```
> xy = st_coordinates(st_centroid(routem))
Warning message:
In st_centroid.sf(routem) :
  st_centroid assumes attributes are constant over geometries of x
> xy
          X        Y
1 -106.2318 28.99859
2 -110.2354 30.98840
3 -109.9571 31.22957
```

then you can add that as a line:

```
> plot(muni$geom)
> lines(xy, col="red", lwd=4)
```

[image]